# How do java resolve relative path like [ new File("filename.txt") ] ?

Tags: java, file, relative-path

When in java I use relative path to create file like this:

```
File file = new File("filename.txt");
```

How program resolve path? In my program I have an issue related to this. When I work I use eclipse  - it run program from compiled files (without packing it to .jar). Ultimately the program will be runing as from jar file or by using some script in ubuntu. In all those 3 cases above code create path in different directory. To fix it I have to just understand how it works. So how do java resolve relative path like this?

Comment: @tahatmat: It's not a duplicate - that question is about `getResource()` which looks on the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

It resolves it relative to your process's current working directory. For example, you can specify that in Eclipse in the run configuration.

Basically, you should either use an absolute filename, or make sure you're running it from an appropriate directory. (You haven't indicated *how* you're running it from a jar file or a script...)

Answer (score 2):

for java, relative paths are relative to your working directory, i.e. the directory from where you start to application. You could do something like `String current = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();` to find out where this is.

Typically, in Eclipse, it's the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

your current running file's directory is say  `c://abc//xyz//yourRunningFile.`

then your file have path like `c://abc//xyz//filename.txt`

this thing happend only if you have not configure it and if you configure from eclipse as Jon said you can make it custom.